# Let $P_3$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree at most three in one variable t.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P_3$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree at most three in one variable $t$. Let $p(t)=t^3 +a_2t^2 +a_1t+a_0$ where $a_0,a_1,a_2 \in\mathbb R$ are fixed constants.

Show that $\{p, \frac{dp}{dt}, \frac{d^2p}{dt^2}, \frac{d^3p}{dt^3}\}$ is a basis for $P_3$.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show your work? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am even unsure on what a basis is. and how the derivative plays a part into solving for the basis.

Comment: Very well. Have you read the definition of basis? Remember it is just a set satisfying some conditions (actually, 2 conditions). You have to check if the given set satisfies such conditions.

Comment: About the derivatives, you just have to remember that the derivative of a polynomial is a polynomial (remember that $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = n\cdot x^{n-1}$ for $n\geq 0$).

Comment: so it would be {p, 3t^2+2a2t+a1, 6t+2a2, 6} for the derivatives. The conditions are if B spans W and B is linearly independent.

Comment: Right! How can we show that a set span a vector space? And how can we show that a set is linearly independent?

Comment: linearly independent if the scalars of the linear combination of the subset are all equal to 0

Comment: and a span is all solutions to a homogeneous equation

Answer (score 1):

So you have to show that $${\cal B} = \{t^3+a_2t^2+a_1t+a_0, 3t^2+2a_2t+a_1, 6t+2a_2, 6\}$$ ia a basis for $V=P_3$.

Of course you can show it by definition of being a basis, and it's pretty straightforward (try it!). But I'll give a solution a little bit short which uses the following result:

> **Lemma:** *If $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space and if $W$ is a $n$-dimensional subspace of $V$, then $W=V$.*

We are going to show that ${\cal B}$ is linearly independent and conclude that $W={\rm span\,}{\cal B}$ is a $4$-dimensional subspace of $V=P_3$, from where we will know that $W=V$ ($P_3$ being a $4$-dimensional vector space).

Write $$\alpha(t^3+a_2t^2+a_1t+a_0)+\beta(3t^2+2a_2t+a_1)+\gamma( 6t+2a_2) + 6\delta = 0,$$ which is just
$$\alpha t^3 + (a_2\alpha+3\beta)t^2 + (a_1\alpha + 2a_2\beta + 6\gamma)t + (a_0\alpha + a_1\beta + 2a_2\gamma + 6 \delta) = 0t^3 + 0t^2 + 0 t + 0$$
and it is possible only if $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta = 0$, what is exactly the definition of ${\cal B}$ being linearly independent.

Using the lemma (and the dimensions of ${\rm span\,}{\cal B}$ and $P_3$), we have that ${\rm span\,}{\cal B} = P_3$.

Therefore ${\cal B}$ is a basis for $P_3$.